# Assigning null to SoundPool object to save resources

Tags: java, android, null

Can assigning "null" to a SoundPool object save some resources for a device if a sound file has been loaded already into the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to release the resources ... call `SoundPool.release()`.  The [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#release()) says:

> Release the `SoundPool` resources. Release all memory and native resources used by the `SoundPool` object. The `SoundPool` can no longer be used and the reference should be set to `null`.

Just nulling the variable that holds your app's `SoundPool` reference *may* make it unreachable, and the resources *may* be reclaimed by the garbage collector at some point in the future.

However, according to my reading of the API, if you either call `release` or just assign `null` to the variable, you will no longer be able to call the `SoundPool` methods to play, pause, resume and so on the sound files that you previously loaded.  So it is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using SoundPool.release(), but after that, I couldn't check exist SoundPool object in the app via if (mSoundPool !=null) or if (mSoundPool ==null) . I can add an extra byte or boolean variable for marking an existing object, but I don't think this is good practice for saving the resources.

Comment: The javadoc I quoted to you explains what to do. *"The `SoundPool` can no longer be used and the reference should be set to `null`."* After calling release on the `SoundPool`, set the reference to `null`.  To be clear calling `release()` releases the resources, and assigning `null` stops you using the object ... and gives you a way to indicate to the app that the pool resources have been released.

Comment: Thanks, now I figured it out.